# Color filter on Ubuntu versions 18.04+

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, gnome-shell, ccsm

Back in the CompizConfig Setting Manager days it was possible to apply screen color filters, which was handy to e.g. [simulate color bindness](https://askubuntu.com/a/46170/161463) or [monochrome colors](https://askubuntu.com/a/102463/161463).

Recent versions of Ubuntu have dropped Unity and therefore CCSM. In [other cases](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028778/161463), i.e., for other CCSM functionality, it is sometimes possible to replace the CCSM functionality with a GNOME Shell extension.

What would be the best replacement on recent Ubuntu versions?